# How can I make the sound of fly or mosquito?

Tags: foley

I wonder how can I make the sound of a mosquito or a fly or any kind of insect? I prefer a comic sound.

Answer (score 1):

A bread and butter way is using a comb with thin paper, put the paper on top of the comb, covering the upside completely, with the teeth pointing at you, and blow between them. Might take a little practice, but does indeed work well!

Answer (score 1):

Jimmy Macdonald was Disney's first sound effects designer and he is responsible for so many of the quintessential cartoon sounds that we associate with. He does a pretty good job of the talking fly/mosquito sound using rubber tubing attached to a kind of drum skin. You can see a demonstration of the sound in this documentary (highly recommended viewing for some general inspiration).

Disney Family Album #4 - Jimmy MacDonald

Answer (score 1):

Rub your knuckles or finger nails fast enough. Record about 20-30 seconds, use a high-pass filter on the recording to get rid of the unnecessary low end, then pitch it up until you get a buzzing sound. It would resemble little wings. :)

You can use various objects to get different timbres with this technique.

Answer (score 0):

I made a video to answer your question:

Use FL Studio, and use a violin plugin like here

- get a single violine synth
- use panning filter on it
- filter it with equalizer
- automate the volume

Answer (score 0):

Press your lips together real tight and then force the air in your mouth out between your lips so they vibrate at a very high pitch.

You can very (vairy?) the pitch by loosening or tightening your lips or using your mouth muscles to change the shape of your lips.

I find this **very comical** when a dog or a cat is in the room.